# Sassdash - Understanding $this-arg

Tags: sass

I am working through the [Sassdash Library](http://davidkpiano.github.io/sassdash/sassdoc/index.html), and there are numerous functions that use a argument `$this-arg`. I am having a lot of trouble understanding what it does. Can anyone simply explain what this does and what some simple use cases might be?

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to how `this` works in JS.